# Websocket server memory leak: large messages

Tags: node.js, websocket, ws

I have a simple websocket server in nodejs using npm ws (the behavior is the same with npm websocket). I have a .NET core back-end communicating directly with the ws server feeding a react front end and sending 30-60KB messages at up to 50Hz

My application is meant at be able to monitor multiple messages at a time. When I add a subscription to these messages, the memory usage by the node server grows tremendously fast and consistent with how many messages I add (the more messages, the faster it grows). But the websocket server or websocket objects seem to hang on the the message buffers for a very long time.

I can build up to several GB of memory usage by the server by adding 5+ messages and waiting just a few minutes. When i stop the messages, the memory usage stops growing, but remains as though the wss keeps everything in memory. I also tried clearing the writable state of the ws objects (commented out), however this causes errors on the client connections. Is there a way that I can safely clear these buffers to keep memory sufficiently low? (Note that for 50Hz information, it's not pertinent to maintain them in buffer for very long anyway, because the streaming is so fast)

```
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  clients.push(ws)

  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {

      clients.forEach(function each(client) {
        if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
          try {
           client.send(message)
          }
          finally {

            // client._socket._writableState.bufferedRequest = null
            // client._socket._writableState.lastBufferedRequest = null
          }
        }
      })


  });

  ws.on('close', function close(data) {
    console.log('disconnected');
    console.log(data);
  });

});
```

Comment: Just for the fun of fighting off memory leaks, if you ever find your self in a situation similar to this code, I'd bet on the array `.push` method which is probably not being cleared after the `close` event.
This is a classic cause of memory leaks.